# How to implement Social Login in a custom ycommercewebservices in Hybris 6.7?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement where we need to implement social login for mobile app.
The backend processing is done in Hybris 6.7. We have extended ycommercewebservices for the same. 
We need to know how can we generate oauth2 token for the same.
Since for oauth2 token we would require userid and password.
But in case for social login we would not be having the password.
Can anybody share the steps to bypass this checks for social login.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend AbstractAuthenticationToken and write a new create token method like

```
private OAuth2AccessToken createToken(CustomerModel customerModel) {

     OAuth2AccessToken token = prepareToken();

     Set<String> resourceIds = new HashSet<>();
     resourceIds.add(RESOURCE_ID);

     OAuthClientDetailsModel client = getOauthClientDetailsDao().findClientById(CLIENT_ID);

     final OAuthAccessTokenModel accessTokenModel = modelService.create(OAuthAccessTokenModel.class);

     OAuth2Request auth2Request = new OAuth2Request(null, client.getClientId(), null, true, null, resourceIds, null, null, null);
     OAuth2Authentication oauthAuthentication = new OAuth2Authentication(auth2Request, createFacebookAuthentication(customerModel.getUid()));

     String authenticationId = this.authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(oauthAuthentication);

     accessTokenModel.setTokenId(extractTokenKey(token.getValue()));
     accessTokenModel.setToken(serializeAccessToken(token));
     accessTokenModel.setAuthenticationId(authenticationId);
     accessTokenModel.setAuthentication(SerializationUtils.serialize(oauthAuthentication));
     accessTokenModel.setClient(client);
     accessTokenModel.setUser(customerModel);
     modelService.saveAll(accessTokenModel, customerModel);
     return deserializeAccessToken((byte[]) accessTokenModel.getToken());
 }
```

You have to call

```
OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = socialLoginService.getAccessToken(socialId, email, firstName, lastName);
```